(Pytorch) How to get the tensors by matching values in other list?
I want to select the values in a two-dimensional tensor by matching them to the list of values.
example
#tensor([[61078, 51477, 28492, 4290, 86920,  2216],
#        [26799, 76684, 23785, 18202, 14552, 98301]])

a 
# Index([61078, 23785, 2216], dtype='int64', length=3)

result
#tensor([[61078, 28492, 2216],
#        [26799, 23785, 98301]])

I tried using torch.where and isin, but they always returned errors.
How can I solve the problem?

Use eq from PyTorch with the any function to create a mask that matches the values in your tensor to the values in your list, then use the mask to index into your tensor:
import torch

t = torch.tensor([[61078, 51477, 28492, 4290, 86920,  2216],
              [26799, 76684, 23785, 18202, 14552, 98301]])
a = torch.tensor([61078, 23785, 2216])
mask = (t[..., None] == a).any(-1)
result = t * mask.long()
print(result)

Output:
tensor([[61078,     0, 28492,     0,     0,  2216],
        [    0,     0, 23785,     0,     0,     0]])


Thank you for your kind comment! May I ask one more question? If I want to remove 0 values in the output, how can I do it?
expected result is as below:
tensor([[28492],
[23785]])

Just modified @Laszlo Hunyadi answer to better match the required output of the question.
import torch

t = torch.tensor([[61078, 51477, 28492, 4290, 86920,  2216],
              [26799, 76684, 23785, 18202, 14552, 98301]])
a = torch.tensor([61078, 23785, 2216])
mask = (t[..., None] == a).any(-1).any(0)

result = t[:,*torch.where(mask)]
print(result)

Output:
tensor([[61078, 28492,  2216],
        [26799, 23785, 98301]])


Thank you for your answer! But I saw the errors on result = t[:,*torch.where(mask)]. 1. SyntaxError: invalid syntax on *. -> remove * -> 2. TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index.

This only work for the 2D case like your example, if you have different dimension then this would fail. If you want a more generalized answer, then you could give a few more examples.

I have tested on my machine andit return true answer for any 2D array case and select by column. If you still have error, try print the value of torch.where(mask)
